# How to fix recording video time duration

Tags: iphone, ios, video-capture

Actually I am able to record a video successfully but I want to record video for 30 second. How can I do this ?

thnx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this default property for setting maximum duration for video recording:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval videoMaximumDuration

Ex :     imagePickerControllerInstance.videoMaximumDuration = 30;
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the videoMaxiumDuration property in UIImagePickerController.

The value is an NSTimeInterval which is specified in seconds, so you'll want to set it to 300 seconds if you want 5 mins of video.

Comment: plz check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455044/set-maximum-recording-duration-while-video-recording-from-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

Try this :: `imgPickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 30;`